# How to fix drush php configuration on the hosting?

Tags: drush

I am facing a pretty award drush problem. In order to run drush I need to use this command on my hosting:

```
/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini 
                 -d memory_limit=128M /home/pisar/opt/drush.php
```

When I run

```
/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini 
                 -d memory_limit=128M /home/pisar/opt/drush.php status
```

it works correctly. But when I try to do the update command:

```
/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini 
                 -d memory_limit=128M /home/pisar/opt/drush.php upc drupal
```

and it fails with the message:

> pm-updatestatus failed

I found out that upc runs drush in subshell with incorrect php. So I added path to php:

```
/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini 
                 -d memory_limit=128M /home/pisar/opt/drush.php 
                 --php=/opt/php/bin/php --debug upc drupal
```

But it also fails without configs. When I pass configs:

```
/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini 
                 -d memory_limit=128M /home/pisar/opt/drush.php 
                 --php=/opt/php/bin/php\ -c\ /home/pisar/etc/php.ini\ 
                 -d\ memory_limit=128M --debug upc drupal
```

it fails because it tries to run them using quoted php with params:

```
Backend invoke: '/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini -d memory_limit=128M' /home/pisar/opt/drush.php --php='/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini -d memory_limit=128M'  [command]
 --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root=/home/pisar/site.com/docs/drupal --uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus drupal 2>&1 [1.45 sec, 14.72 MB]
'/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini -d memory_limit=128M' /home/pisar/opt/drush.php --php='/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini -d memory_limit=128M'  --backend=2      [notice]
--verbose --debug --root=/home/pisar/site.com/docs/drupal --uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus drupal 2>&1 [1.45 sec, 14.73 MB]
The command could not be executed successfully (returned: /opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini -d memory_limit=128M: not found
```

I put this:

```
export DRUSH_PHP='/opt/php/bin/php'
export PHP_INI='/home/pisar/etc/php.ini'
export PHP_OPTIONS='-d memory_limit=128M'
```

into `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`. Then ran without `--php`, but nothing helped.

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `--php-options` parameter. The working command looks like this:

```
/opt/php/bin/php -c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini -d memory_limit=128M 
                    /home/pisar/opt/drush.php --php=/opt/php/bin/php
                    --php-options="-c /home/pisar/etc/php.ini
                    -d memory_limit=128M" upc -y drupal
```